# ExtJS rendering after data loading

Tags: java, extjs

On the page, you need to draw one of the two icons. 'card.recurrentsupported' is of type 'Boolean'. At the input `value == null`. After loading the data, `value == true, false or null`. In the current implementation, the `close` icon is first drawn on the page, and after 0.5 seconds, after loading the data, if `value == true`, the icon is redrawn to `check`.

How can I wait for the data to load and then draw the icons?

`renderer: function` has additional parameters `metadata, record, RowIndex, colIndex, store, view`. Maybe I can use them to get a flag about loading data?

```
items: [                
            {
                ...
            },
            {
                fieldLabel: 'Support for recurrences',
                bind: '{card.recurrentSupported}',
                renderer: function (value) {
                    return value != null && value ? '<i class="fa fa-check text-green"></i>' : '<i class="fa fa-close text-red"></i>';
                }
            },
        ]
```

Card.js

```
Ext.define('App.view.card.Card', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
alias: 'widget.card',
requires: [
    'App.view.card.CardController'
],
controller: 'app.card',

viewModel: {
    security: {
        allowManageCard: 'card-update'
    },
    formulas: {
        merchantId: function (get) {
            var card = get('card');
            return card != null ? card.get('merchant') : null
        }
    }
},
modelValidation: true,

bind: {
    title: '{card.maskedPan}'
},

menuToken: 'cards',
tools: [
    {
        xtype: 'container',
        html: [
            '<ul class="breadcrumbs">',
            '<li><a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>',
            '<li><a href="#cards">Cards</a></li>',
            '</ul>'
        ]
    }
],

defaults: {
    xtype: 'container',
    layout: 'form',
    defaultType: 'displayfield'
},

cls: 'adminkit-panel',

items: [
    {
        bind: {
            data: {
                blocked: '{card.blocked}',
                status: '{card.status}'
            }
        },
        data: {empty: true},
        tpl: [
            ...
        ],
        width: 70
    },
    {
        columnWidth: 0.5,
        items: [
            ...                
        ]
    },
    {
        columnWidth: 0.5,
        items: [
            ...
            {
                fieldLabel: 'Support for recurrences',
                bind: '{card.recurrentSupported}',
                renderer: function (value) {
                    return value != null && value ? '<i class="fa fa-check text-green"></i>' : '<i class="fa fa-close text-red"></i>';
                }
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

});

CardController.js

```
Ext.define('App.view.card.CardController', {
alias: 'controller.app.card',
extend: 'AdminKit.EntityViewController',

entityType: 'Card',

initViewModel: function() {
    var vm = this.getViewModel();
    vm.bind('{merchantId}', function (merchantId) {
        if (vm.get('merchantId') != null){
            Rpc.MerchantManager.resolve({id: merchantId}, function (err, res){
                vm.set('merchantName', res != null ? res.name : null)
            })
        }
    })
},

...
});
```

I solved the problem by replacing `bind: '{card.recurrentSupported}'`
with `bind: {value: {isrecurrent: '{card.recurrentsupported}'}}`. This way we can track when the data was loaded. At the start of rendering, value = "", and after loading the data, value = {isRecurrent: true, false or unndefined}. Sometimes, an object is created, but the data does not have time to load, then value.isRecurrent == null.

```
{
                fieldLabel: 'Support for recurrences',
                bind: {value: {isRecurrent: '{card.recurrentSupported}'}},
                renderer: function (value) {
                    if (!Ext.isEmpty(value) && value.isRecurrent != null) {
                        return value.isRecurrent ? '<i class="fa fa-check text-green"></i>'
                            : '<i class="fa fa-close text-red"></i>';
                    } else if (!Ext.isEmpty(value) && value.isRecurrent === undefined) {
                        return '<i class="fa fa-close text-red"></i>';
                    } else {
                        return ''
                    }
                }
            }
```

Option, with the addition of a field that is exactly filled in

```
{
                fieldLabel: 'Support for recurrences',
                bind: {value:  {pan: '{card.maskedPan}', recurrentSupported: '{card.recurrentSupported}'}},
                renderer: function (value) {
                    if (value.pan == null) {
                        return '';
                    }
                    return value.recurrentSupported ? '<i class="fa fa-check text-green"></i>'
                        : '<i class="fa fa-close text-red"></i>';
                }
            },
```

Comment: How do you load data? Please include that part of your code. You can for example wait for load to complete, and display the form or whatever only after it is loaded, and show a progress indicator until then.

Comment: We take the data from the database. Added more code. I'm new to js. Waiting for the form to load is a good idea. Can you tell me how this can be done?

Comment: One option is that you don't add the components affected by the data load in you view definition, but only after data is loaded. You can use `add` method on the panel component for example, and add items there.

Comment: Another option is that you set a mask on the panel initally (like `myPanel.mask('Please wait...');`) and after data is loaded call `myPanel.unmask();`. This way the user will only see the result.

Answer (score 1):

There are different approaches possible.

***EVENT LISTENER***

```
stores: {
    myStore: {
        url: 'getDataUrl',
        listeners: {
            load: function() {
                const view = Ext.create('newView')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***DATABINDING***

xtype: 'myView'
bind: {hidden: '{myStore.loading}'}